# How to avoid warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm getting warning in below code i.e

```
uint64_t val = 0x1234567812345678;
uint32_t addr = 0x12345678;
*(volatile uint64_t *)(addr) = val;
```

> ```
> $gcc  -o test test.c
> test.c: In function ‘main’:
> test.c:8:4: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
>    *(volatile uint64_t *)(addr) = val;
> ```

Its a embedded environment and trying to implement Flash algorithm, where only double word can be programmed. 
What is the best way to convert uint32_t addr to uint64_t volatile address?

Comment: What are you trying to do? This is unlikely work, unless you are on freestanding envoriment (basically on embedded system without operating system).

Comment: you should use `uintptr_t` instead of `uint32_t`.

Comment: The question you ask in the text does not match the code.
Do you want 64 -> 32 or 32 -> 64

Comment: Why dont you try *(volatile uint64_t *)(0x12345678) = val;

Comment: If you are compiling for the embedded environment, why are you using `gcc`? If you are compiling from 64-bit Linux to same platform this may make sense, but if you are cross-compiling for other system you may have to use other compiler (correct me gcc experts if I'm wrong).

Comment: OK, what is the effect of using that expression instead? [*(volatile uint64_t *)((uintptr_t)addr) = val;]  actually that expression remove error.

Comment: In your situation, what is `double word`?

Comment: What is `sizeof (volatile uint64_t *)` on your machine?